# GridView click listener type problems

Tags: android, eclipse, sample

I'm trying to develop Apps for Android with ECLIPSE, but I have too many errors.
I mean, while trying a code written on **GOOGLE's developing site** - [For Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)
I recieve many errors.

for example:

> The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in
>   the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments
>   (new OnItemClickListener(){})

this is the error that I recieve for that code:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
}
```

Please help me to figure this out. \:

Thanks a lot !!!

**FIRST QUESTION SOLVED**

Now I have another problem:

Yeah thanks for that !

Now it shows me another error:

> The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is
>   not applicable for the arguments (RelativeLayout, String, int)

while my activity code is:

```
package grid.View;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(RelativeLayout.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the rest of the code from your activity. Include your imports section too. Since there are many different "versions" of OnClickListener you may have the incorrect one imported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method implementation missing. Like shown at the link you just posted, you should do:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Your "onclick" handling here
    }
});
```

Also, have you imported everything that you need? Try Ctrl+Shift+o in Eclipse, so that it will make the necessary imports for you.

Answer (score 1):

replace RelativeLayout.this with getApplicationContext()